# An efficient way to convert between MKL and Armadillo types

Tags: linear-algebra, software, intel-mkl

We use Armadillo a lot in our code but there are places where we prefer to use MKL directly from Vector Math Library. We have cx_vec i.e. vector of doubles. But the exp function of armadillo uses std::exp which is not great so we started using MKL for it. The problem comes when converting cx_vec into MKL_Complex16 arrays and back. The method works but I am not sure if there is a better way to do it or a recommended way. Is there a better way to use MKL from Armadillo? Here is the example of code we use currently. Note the cast at the begining and a copy at the end which is what I would like to rewrite. Any suggestion is welcome.

```
void Exp_MKL(const cx_vec& VectorInput, cx_vec& VectorOutput) {
  if (VectorInput.size() != VectorOutput.size())
    VectorOutput.set_size(VectorInput.size());

  const MKL_Complex16* in = reinterpret_cast<const MKL_Complex16*>(VectorInput.memptr());
  const int size = VectorInput.n_elem;
  MKL_Complex16* out = (MKL_Complex16*) mkl_malloc(size * sizeof(MKL_Complex16), 64);

  VZEXP(&size, in, out);
  cx_vec newoutput(reinterpret_cast<cx_double*>(out), VectorInput.size(), false);
  VectorOutput = newoutput;
  mkl_free(out);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just give the VZEXP function the memptr in the VectorOutput? That would remove the allocations.

Comment: I suppose that should work. Thanks.Is this what you are referring to? VZEXP(&size, (MKL_Complex16*)VectorInput.memptr(), (MKL_Complex16*)VectorOutput.memptr());

Comment: Yop. You may want to check that the output and input sizes are the same, but other than that.

Answer (score 2):

Note that Armadillo's `cx_double` (which is used by `cx_vec`) is just an alias for `std::complex<double>`, so in fact you're converting between `std::complex<double>` and `MKL_Complex16`. The only requirement for the `reinterpret_cast` to behave as expected is the compatibility of memory layouts of the involved structures -- in this case they are compatible. The [MKL User Guide](http://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/sugon/intel/mkl/mkl_userguide/GUID-9A806754-1453-4433-9254-6FEA2C66B21B.htm) even has an example where `MKL_Complex16` is redefined to `std::complex<double>`, in which case there is no need to do the casts manually and you can just pass the Armadillo pointers directly.